# Creating channel permission overwrites

Tags: discord.js

I am creating a bot command so that when you type `!setup` it sets up the whole server (creating channels and roles, etc). I have already set it to create the roles and channels but there are some channels that only specific roles can type in, whereas, other roles can only read the channel. I don't know how to set up permission overwrites for certain roles.

I have already looked on the Discord.js documentation and it doesn't help much. I receive an error that `supplied parameter was neither a user nor a role`, but I don't know how to gain the role ID.

```js
message.guild.createRole({
  name: 'Admin',
  color: '#2494ad',
  permissions: ['ADMINISTRATOR', 'VIEW_AUDIT_LOG', 'MANAGE_GUILD', 'MANAGE_CHANNELS', 'SEND_TTS_MESSAGES', 'CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE', 'KICK_MEMBERS', 'BAN_MEMBERS', 'ADD_REACTIONS', 'PRIORITY_SPEAKER', 'READ_MESSAGES', 'SEND_MESSAGES', 'MANAGE_MESSAGES', 'EMBED_LINKS', 'ATTACH_FILES', 'READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY', 'MENTION_EVERYONE', 'USE_EXTERNAL_EMOJIS', 'CONNECT', 'SPEAK', 'MUTE_MEMBERS', 'DEAFEN_MEMBERS', 'MOVE_MEMBERS', 'USE_VAD', 'CHANGE_NICKNAME', 'MANAGE_NICKNAMES', 'MANAGE_ROLES', 'MANAGE_WEBHOOKS', 'MANAGE_EMOJIS']
});

message.guild.createRole({
  name: 'Requesting Role',
  color: '#1bb738',
  permissions: ['READ_MESSAGES', 'SEND_MESSAGES', 'READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY',]
});

//Categories and Channels
message.guild.createChannel('clan-communications', {
  type: 'category',
  permissionOverwrites: [{
    id:'25311096',
    deny: ['SEND_MESSAGES']
  }]
});

//Permissions
message.channel.overwritePermissions('25311096', {
  SEND_MESSAGES: false
});

break;
```

I would like roles to have base permissions for the whole server. But certain roles have overwrites for different channels. Instead it says the `supplied parameter was neither a user nor a role.`

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, welcome to Stack Overflow. Hopefully we can be of help to you.

**Let's walk through a solution step by step to achieve your desired result.**

When you create your roles, you should declare a variable to store them. That way, you can use what the client just created later on. Since [`Guild.createRole()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=createRole) returns a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), we can save the fulfilled result into a variable.

*Note that the keyword [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) must be placed in async context (within an [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)).*

```js
const vip = await message.guild.createRole('VIP', { ... });
```

Then, when you need to use that role, you can refer to the variable.

```js
await message.guild.createChannel('VIPs Only', {
  type: 'category',
  permissionOverwrites: [
    {
      id: vip.id,
      allow: ['READ_MESSAGES']
    }, {
      id: message.guild.defaultRole.id, // @everyone role
      deny: ['READ_MESSAGES']
    }
  ]
});
```

If the role already exists, you can retrieve it from the [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection) of roles returned by [`Guild.roles`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=roles).

```js
const testRole = message.guild.roles.get('IDhere');
const adminRole = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === 'Admin');
```

**Other simple improvements.**

- In your code snippet, I don't see any error handling. The methods you're using return promises. If an error occurs in any, the promise state will become rejected. Any rejected promises that aren't caught will throw errors. To fix this, attach [`catch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) methods to each promise (better for individual handling) or wrap async code in a [`try...catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) statement.
- When creating your Admin role, know that the `ADMINISTRATOR` permission automatically grants all other permissions (and allows users to bypass channel-specific permissions). Therefore, there's no need to list any other permission, or change the role's permission overwrites in any channels.
- Your IDs in your code don't appear to be valid. Discord IDs are [snowflakes](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/Snowflake), represented by strings of 18 digits. You can access them through Developer Mode in Discord. However, you shouldn't have to hard-code them with this solution, unless they already exist.
- In the permissions array for your `Requesting Role` role, you have an extra comma.

Comment: i do not understand what the await/async function is and what i should put there

Comment: (Sorry for the delayed response, I never saw a notification.) I'd suggest reading up on some of the documentation I hyperlinked. An async function returns a promise, which means you must wait for a response. You can do so by using the keyword `await`. To use `await`, however, it must be inside of an async function. So, if the most relevant function the code is inside is the message event callback, define it as async (`async message => {...}` or `async function(message) {...}`).

Comment: Thanks again for this. I think you told me about this in another question but thanks for the response anyway.